# ANDROID NDK - android: command not found

Tags: android, path, android-ndk, cygwin

I was trying to go through the first sample exercise provided in Android NDK. I was trying to run the following command on cygwin

```
android update project –p
```

However, I am getting  `android: command not found error`.

I checked my PATH variables. It already had `ANDROID_HOME` , `ANDROID_HOME/platforms`, `ANDROID_HOME/tools`, `ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

One thing that I noticed was that there is `no application named android` in any of the folder. There is just `an executable JAR file named android`. Is that OK , or , this is my mistake ?

My PATH value added on request

```
bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/include:/cygdrive/c/Ant2/bin:/cygdrive/c/Android/android-sdk/tools:/cygdrive/c/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools:/cygdrive/c/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8b:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/lib:/cygdrive/c/Android/android-sdk/platforms:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin:/usr/lib/lapack
```

Can anyone predict what am I missing ?

Thanks :)

Comment: can you post the complete output of `echo %PATH%` or your entire `PATH` definition ?

Comment: Added relevant part of my PATH

Comment: To be Honest i simply DIDNT define a JAVA_HOME in my .profile and the issue was resolved. I did define however my sdk tools path, sdk platform-tools, and my ant path

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use:

```
$ android.bat update project --path .
```

Answer (score 1):

There are errors in your approach:

- you don't need Cygwin and you should not use it with the latest NDK or SDK ( and probably never, in any case ) because they are distributed for Windows, they are supposed to work in a Windows environment and not under Cygwin; this is an approach used for really old versions of the Android NDK ( Cygwin ) but not for the latest.
- the Android SDK requires the JDK **6** not **7**

Supposing that you will fix this errors, the part that you are still missing is:

- right after the download of the official SDK you have to run the manager at least once, download the platform-tools and at least 1 platform, the android executable is usually included in the `tools` directory in the root of your SDK directory
- you android command is incorrect and will not work even with android installed correctly, this is a correct version among all the ones that are possible `android update project –p . -t android-10`
- Android has nothing to do with jar files in strict terms, jar files are container used by developers to add functionalities, you can see them as libraries, but Android does not care about jar files and apk files are only required to contain `.dex` files, files for the Dalvik VM

This `android ...` command is used to update the building setup to a particular path and target, after that you should have at least the minimum configuration to produce an apk if the source code is well written and organized.

If the application is only written in Java you only need to build the apk at this point, you can do this with an IDE like Eclipse or with `ant` doing only `ant debug` or `ant release` from the root of your project.

If everything will be fine you will find the apk in your `<project root>/bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\Iuliia\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.bat update project --path .
```

is the same as

```
android update project –p
```

if you haven't `android` in your PATH. Don't forget to give your path to Android SDK.