# ndk-build command not found in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

I have successfully generated .h file using javah, now i want to build my android-ndk hello world project. But it says command not found
    nespl@nespl-pc:~$ ndk-build
    ndk-build: command not found

this is my path

```
nespl@nespl-pc:~$ echo $PATH
/home/nespl/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build:/home/nespl/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/nespl/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/tools:/home/nespl/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/platform-tools:/home/nespl/gsutil
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749382/android-ndk-android-command-not-found

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your PATH should include the root directory of your NDK:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/nespl/android-ndk-r8
```

instead of your current:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/nespl/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build
```

Comment: `./ndk-build` instead of `ndk-build`?

Comment: thanks i got it working, i have put android-ndk-r8 instead of android-ndk-r8d, was typing wrong path earlier. thanks for response

Comment: What's different between $export NDK, $export ANDROID_NDK, $export PATH ?!

Comment: I run these three command on App terminal .                                        export ANDROID_SDK="/Users/Library/Android/sdk"
export ANDROID_NDK="/Users/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK"                                                                Then Run NDK_BUILD . Error >>  line 2: dirname: command not found
line 3: /Users//Documents/RD/sample/build/ndk-build: No such file or directory

Comment: it's bad solution because you won't be able to use `echo $NDK`